# How to use the fonts I've picked from google fonts

Tags: css, frontend

So, let's say I've picked a font from google fonts with multiple size/bold/italic.

How do I use the different sizes that I've picked? I can't seem to change the size accordingly.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400&display=swap');

.box1 {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

.box2 {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans 500;0', sans-serif;
}

.box3 {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans 700;0', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Flexbox 3</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="main1">
      <div class="box1">box 1</div>
      <div class="box2">box 2</div>
      <div class="box3">box 3</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400&display=swap');

.box1 {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

.box2 {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.box3 {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```